# docker-compose volume bug: File shows up in ls, but accessing it says that file doesnt exists

Tags: docker-volume

I'm trying to mount some certification files from letsencrypt. They are sudo protected (need sudo access), however, since docker has sudo access, that shouldnt be the problem. When I bash into the container, and go into the mounted folder inside the container, the files show up in the `ls` command, however, `cat`-ing the files tells me that said files doesn't exists. When I run the container normally, geoserver says that it cant find the certificate/private key files and generates its own self-signed certificates.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
        geoserver:
                container_name: geoserver
                image: "kartoza/geoserver:2.22.0"
                volumes:
                        - ./geoserver-data:/opt/geoserver/data_dir
                        - /etc/letsencrypt/live/geo.geplant.com.br:/etc/certs
                ports:
                        - 0.0.0.0:8080:8080
                        - 0.0.0.0:443:8443
                restart: always
                environment:
                        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=
                        - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER=
                        - GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/opt/geoserver/data_dir
                        - GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR=/opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
                        - SSL=true
                healthcheck:
                        test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:8080/ || exit 1
                        interval: 1m30s
                        timeout: 10s
                        retries: 3
```

Inside the containers mounted volume:
[image]
t
Cat'ing the file
[image]

I think this is some sort of protection going on, bc the README file works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was that the certificate files were only symlinks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this mounting the volume in this folder and passing the remaining path through env name.

Im new here, but this links takes to the screenshoot

[docker compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65U0M.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Instead of linking images you can also put the text snippet as code-block here, that improves your answer :)